# Using a made list in different class

Tags: c#, list, class, methods

I made a list using the next script:

```
private void Skills_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
...
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(Database);

List<String> Item_Name = new List<String>();
List<double> Sell_Price = new List<double>();
List<double> Buy_Price = new List<double>();

foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    Item_Name.Add(dict[key].name);
    Sell_Price.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dict[key].sell_average));
    Buy_Price.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dict[key].buy_average));
}

}
```

Then, I created a method:

```
public double S(string name, List<String> Item_Name, List<double> Sell_Price)
{
    int ind = Item_Name.FindIndex(s=> s==name);
    double SP = Sell_Price[ind];

    return SP;
}
```

In the end, I would like to use this method in a different method (when a button is pushed in the wpf), but I receive an error that the lists `Item_Name,Sell_Price,Buy_Price` are not known in that class.

How can I make them "global" to other classes?

All the answers I found in here speak about created always new lists.

Thank you.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking; the variables you defined are local to a method called `Skills_Button_Click`. Do you mean you want to share these between methods in the same class, or make them available to another class as well, or something else?

Comment: all of the methods are inside a wpf mainwindow so I want to share between methods. Updated the question thank you.

Comment: Just move those local declarations into the class, so they’re in scope for the whole class and not local to a method.

Comment: Make em class level variables, declare them as `public` , and include `shared` if required..that's all :)

Comment: @zackraiyan they don't need to be `public` unless they need to be accessed from outside the class, and there's no such thing as `shared` in C#

Comment: @series0ne , my bad .. i meant `static` :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In that case you extract this to a public method which returns all of this data like below and call it wherever needed

```
public Tuple<List<String>, List<Double>, List<Double>> GetEventData(Database db)
{
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(db);

List<String> Item_Name = new List<String>();
List<double> Sell_Price = new List<double>();
List<double> Buy_Price = new List<double>();

foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    Item_Name.Add(dict[key].name);
    Sell_Price.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dict[key].sell_average));
    Buy_Price.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dict[key].buy_average));
}

Tuple t = Tuple.Create(Item_Name, Sell_Price, Buy_Price);
return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would wrap the properties into a single model. *Notice that I'm using `decimal` rather than `double` as this is the recommendation when dealing with currency.*

```
public sealed class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string itemName, decimal sellPrice, decimal buyPrice)
    {
        ItemName = itemName;
        SellPrice = sellPrice;
        BuyPrice = buyPrice;
    }

    public string ItemName { get; }
    public decimal SellPrice { get; }
    public decimal BuyPrice { get; }
}
```

Then I would design my class to have an enumerable member to store the results

```
class WhateverYourClassIsCalled
{
    private IEnumerable<ItemModel> items;

    private void Skills_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items = GetItems();
    }

    private IEnumerable<ItemModel> GetItems()
    {
        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Item> dictionary = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(database);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Item> item in dictionary)
        {
            yield return new ItemModel(
                itemName: item.Key,
                sellPrice: item.Value.sell_average,
                buyPrice: item.Value.buy_average);
        }
    }

    // You called this method, "S", which is a poor name!
    private decimal GetSellPrice(string itemName)
    {
        // Notice that SingleOrDefault here might be null, so have a think about how you want to handle that.
        return items
            .SingleOrDefault(item => item.ItemName == itemName)
            .SellPrice;
    }
}
```

**Advantages**

- Your item data is encapsulated (look up 4 pillars of OOP).
- Your item data isn't disconnected by being stored in different members (You just have to deal with `items` rather than `Item_Name`, `Sell_Price` and `Buy_Price`).
- Your `items` member is secure in that you cannot add, remove or clear the collection. You can only iterate over it or reassign it.
- Methods are split into clear responsibilities.
- Your `ItemModel` is immutable, which is a good thing in *most* cases.